# get menu from ListFragment

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

My MainActivity have 3 different ListFragment (each has their own java file) which I can navigate through swiping left and right. There is an EditText that I want to access on Action Bar. How can I access it from any of the ListFragment? ListFragment does not have onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) so I am not sure how to implement those code (supposed to be used in MainActivity) to get the EditText from the ListFragment

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
final EditText editText = (EditText) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragment has [onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, MenuInflater)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu,%20android.view.MenuInflater)):

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

it will be called only if you call

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

From the documentation

> Initialize the contents of the Activity's standard options menu. You
>   should place your menu items in to menu.

Comment: Wow thanks! I should have looked up the documentation clearly before asking this.